# Jira REST api, update a custom field options specific to a project

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am using REST api to update a custom field (customfield_10706) list (to add more options in the dropdown). I am using,
/rest/api/3/customField/10706/option
body is,

```
{
  "options": [
    {
      "value": "Added via API121212"
    }
  ]
}
```

This works correctly and adds value. But I am not sure which project it is adding to, as there are several projects in Jira and the custom field is the same in all projects. Is there an option to add ProjectKey or ProjectId somewhere for it to add in the specific project?

Does this have to do anything with the basic auth user used to authenticate the REST api call?

Answer (score 0):

The REST API will add the value to the custom field, irrespective of what Projects are using that field. If you have 10 Projects using that one custom field, then all those Projects will be affected by the change, exactly the same as if you modified the custom field's values via the web interface.

If you want to limit the effect of changing a custom field to one Project, only use that custom field in that one project.